# Como agrupar colunas em uma só? Problema de R

Tags: r

Como eu posso **agrupar essas variáveis** em uma só, denominada **Violência**, que indica se a pessoa foi violentada ou não?

Estou tentando montar a dummy mas aparece um erro por causa do número de observações:

```
  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, violencia, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 1090152 rows, data has 90846
```

Este é o código que eu montei:

---

```
   data.modelo = data.frame(Sexo,UF,Urbano.Rural,Quantidade.comodos,Idade,Cor,Tipo.Escola,
                         Ofenca,Grito,Ameaca.Propria,Ameaca.Proximo,Destruicao.de.Bens,Tapa,
                         Empurrao,Soco.Chute,Estrangulacao,Ameaça.Ferimento.com.Arma,
                         Abuso.Sexual,Ameaça.Sexual)
library(dplyr)

Agressoes <- c("Ofenca", "Grito", "Ameaca.Propria", "Ameaca.Proximo", 
               "Destruicao.de.Bens", "Tapa", "Empurrao", "Soco.Chute", 
               "Estrangulacao", "Ameaça.Ferimento.com.Arma", "Abuso.Sexual", 
               "Ameaça.Sexual")


data.modelo$violencia = ifelse(Agressoes=="Sim",1,0)
```

---

O nome das colunas que eu quero agrupar são:

- Ofensa
- Grito
- Ameaca.Propria
- Ameaca.Proximo
- Destruicao.de.Bens
- Tapa
- Empurrao
- Soco.Chute
- Estrangulacao
- Ameaça.Ferimento.com.Arma
- Abuso.Sexual
- Ameaça.Sexual

Assim:

- Se a observação indicar "**Sim**", para qualquer uma das agressões, a nova variável violência deve conter "Sim" nesta observação.
- Somente tal conterá "**Não**", se todas as violências listadas estiverem "Não" contidas

Segue link para a Base de Dados utilizada:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v4fzqwp44hw45in/AADd2UVXyi7OM4gSEFM-5tMJa?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução R base:

1. Usando o vetor `Agressoes` para ficar só com as colunas relevantes, `dados.modelo[Agressoes] == "Sim"` dá uma matriz lógica;
2. Os valores `FALSE/TRUE` são internamente `0/1`, e para ter a quantidade de `"Sim"` em cada linha, soma-se com `rowSums`, removendo os `NA`'s;
3. Cada soma deve ser maior que 0;
4. Converte-se o valor da comparação no ponto anterior para `"integer"`.

E isto só precisa de uma linha de código.

```
dados.modelo$violencia <- as.integer(rowSums(dados.modelo[Agressoes] == "Sim", na.rm = TRUE) > 0L)
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra possibilidade é pivotar o dataset e, se for o caso, aplicar a função `dplyr::if_else()`

```
library(rio)
library(tidyverse)
```

Importando o dataset

```
dados.modelo <- rio::import("dados.modelo.csv", setclass = "tibble")
```

criar o vetor com as colunas de interesse:

```
Agressoes <- c("Ofenca", "Grito", "Ameaca.Propria", "Ameaca.Proximo", 
               "Destruicao.de.Bens", "Tapa", "Empurrao", "Soco.Chute", 
               "Estrangulacao", "Ameaça.Ferimento.com.Arma", "Abuso.Sexual", 
               "Ameaça.Sexual")
```

Ao realizar a pivotagem, você tem a coluna "violência" e a coluna "valor" com os valores "Sim" ou "Não"

```
dados.modelo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Agressoes,
               names_to = "violencia", 
               values_to = "valor")
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 1,090,152 × 10
      V1 Sexo   UF       Urbano.Rural Quantidade.comodos Idade Cor    Tipo.…¹ viole…² valor
   <int> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>                     <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
 1     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ofenca  Não  
 2     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Grito   Não  
 3     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ameaca… Não  
 4     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ameaca… Não  
 5     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Destru… Não  
 6     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Tapa    Não  
 7     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Empurr… Não  
 8     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Soco.C… Não  
 9     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Estran… Não  
10     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ameaça… Não  
# … with 1,090,142 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​Tipo.Escola, ²​violencia
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Se precisar de valores do tipo "1" (Sim) ou "0" (Não), basta complementar com um `mutate()` + `if_else()`:

```
dados.modelo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Agressoes,
               names_to = "violencia", 
               values_to = "valor") %>% 
  mutate(valor = if_else(condition = valor == "Sim", 
                             true = 1, 
                             false = 0))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 1,090,152 × 10
      V1 Sexo   UF       Urbano.Rural Quantidade.comodos Idade Cor    Tipo.…¹ viole…² valor
   <int> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>                     <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ofenca      0
 2     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Grito       0
 3     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ameaca…     0
 4     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ameaca…     0
 5     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Destru…     0
 6     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Tapa        0
 7     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Empurr…     0
 8     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Soco.C…     0
 9     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Estran…     0
10     1 Mulher Rondônia Urbano                        5    55 Branca NA      Ameaça…     0
# … with 1,090,142 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​Tipo.Escola, ²​violencia
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Um alternativa é a usar função `case_when()` em conjunto com a função `mutate` onde é possível filtrar as variáveis que você quiser utilizando o operador OU (`|`), onde se uma OU outra variável possuir um `Sim` ele  cria uma nova coluna indicando `Violencia=='sim'`.

A vantagem desse método é que se você quiser tirar um tipo de violência específica da sua lista basta não declara-la, que aquele individuo  `X` (linha) será marcado como `Violencia='nao'`.

Caso você quiser adicionar uma nova coluna com o valor 1 para `Violencia=sim` e valor 0 para `Violencia=nao` pode criar uma nova coluna usando `mutate` e `case_when` de novo no final.

OBS: Atenção para `encoding = "UTF-8"` para codificar o tipo de dados importado do `csv`.

Código

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.modelo<-read.csv("C:/Users/wesley/Downloads/dados.modelo.csv",
                      header = TRUE,
                      sep = ",",
                      encoding = "UTF-8")%>%
  dplyr::mutate(Violencia=case_when(
    Ofenca=='Sim'|
    Grito=='Sim'|
    Ameaca.Propria=='Sim'|
    Ameaca.Proximo=='Sim'|
    Destruicao.de.Bens=='Sim'|
    Tapa=='Sim'|
    Empurrao=='Sim'|
    Soco.Chute=='Sim'|
    Estrangulacao=='Sim'|
    Ameaça.Ferimento.com.Arma=='Sim'|
    Abuso.Sexual=='Sim'|
    Ameaça.Sexual=='Sim'~'sim',
    TRUE~'nao'
  ))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(Violencia2=case_when(
    Violencia=='sim'~1,
    TRUE~0
  ))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Saída

```r
head(data.modelo, 10)
#>     X   Sexo       UF Urbano.Rural Quantidade.comodos Idade    Cor  Tipo.Escola
#> 1   1 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  5    55 Branca         <NA>
#> 2   2 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  4    19  Parda         <NA>
#> 3   3 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  8    45  Preta         <NA>
#> 4   4 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  1    58  Preta         <NA>
#> 5   5 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  2    28  Parda Rede privada
#> 6   6  Homem Rondônia       Urbano                  4    81  Parda         <NA>
#> 7   7 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  6    41  Parda         <NA>
#> 8   8 Mulher Rondônia       Urbano                  4    38 Branca         <NA>
#> 9   9  Homem Rondônia       Urbano                  3    33  Parda         <NA>
#> 10 10  Homem Rondônia       Urbano                  3    81  Parda         <NA>
#>    Ofenca Grito Ameaca.Propria Ameaca.Proximo Destruicao.de.Bens Tapa Empurrao
#> 1     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 2     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 3     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 4     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 5     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 6     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 7     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 8     Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#> 9     Sim   Sim            Não            Sim                Não  Não      Não
#> 10    Não   Não            Não            Não                Não  Não      Não
#>    Soco.Chute Estrangulacao Ameaça.Ferimento.com.Arma Abuso.Sexual
#> 1         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 2         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 3         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 4         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 5         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 6         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 7         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 8         Não           Não                       Não          Não
#> 9         Não           Não                       Não          Sim
#> 10        Não           Não                       Não          Não
#>    Ameaça.Sexual Violencia Violencia2
#> 1            Não       nao          0
#> 2            Não       nao          0
#> 3            Não       nao          0
#> 4            Não       nao          0
#> 5            Não       nao          0
#> 6            Não       nao          0
#> 7            Não       nao          0
#> 8            Não       nao          0
#> 9            Não       sim          1
#> 10           Não       nao          0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>